# Google Maps API issue - Browser Not Supported Error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

Tested html code and Javascript which renders maps in Chrome and Firefox. When called from our application the maps will not render and we get the Browser Not Supported Error. Tested using Chrome 62 and Firefox 56.0.2. Map API Key is valid and tested. Using Devtools see no errors in the htm and javascript code.

We use a gis server to house the code that renders the maps for Google Maps, Bing and Custom GIS map servers. Application server houses a DB that has the URL for all the map connections. These URLs are used by client applications to render maps on PC, Android and iOS devices

Comment: Saying that there is an issue with no code won't help anyone to help you. Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by adding the frozen version in the javascript

Now the map tiles render.  Having issue with other script errors but I thinks I can fix